# Magento password reset error when gender and/or date of birth is required

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, passwords, reset

I'm running a 1.7.0.2 Magento website. For this website, I recently activated the required "gender" and "date of birth" options for users. This means that some existing users haven't filled in their gender and date of birth yet. The problem is, if any of these users has forgotten their password and try to reset it they get the following error:

```
The Date of Birth is required.
Gender is required.
Your password reset link has expired.
```

This error occurs after trying to type in their preferred new password and submitting this entry.

When "gender" and "date of birth" are NOT required the password reset acts normally.

I have only found [one post](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/291290/) on this topic, but no answer yet.

Comment: You have answered your question in your own post. If gender and DOB is required and user tried to reset password at that time magento check user profile and it found profile is not completed. So, first need to complete profile then other account process can be performed. OR you can avoid this issue after running a sql query to set default gender and current date as DOB to each and every user.

Comment: I understand, but that is not possible. If a user has forgotten his/her password, he/she is unable to login and complete his/her profile.

Comment: I think the following provides a good answer:
http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29595/customer-reset-passowrd-issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to override 
`Mage_Customer_AccountController` controller `resetPasswordPostAction()` action

after overriding your function look like this

```
public function resetPasswordPostAction()
    {
        $resetPasswordLinkToken = (string) $this->getRequest()->getQuery('token');
        $customerId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getQuery('id');
        $password = (string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('password');
        $passwordConfirmation = (string) $this->getRequest()->getPost('confirmation');

        try {
            $this->_validateResetPasswordLinkToken($customerId, $resetPasswordLinkToken);
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('customer')->__('Your password reset link has expired.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        }

        $errorMessages = array();
        if (iconv_strlen($password) <= 0) {
            array_push($errorMessages, Mage::helper('customer')->__('New password field cannot be empty.'));
        }
        /** @var $customer Mage_Customer_Model_Customer */
        $customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);

        $customer->setPassword($password);
        $customer->setConfirmation($passwordConfirmation);
        $validationErrorMessages = $customer->validate();
        if (is_array($validationErrorMessages)) {
            //$errorMessages = array_merge($errorMessages, $validationErrorMessages);
        }

        if (!empty($errorMessages)) {
            $this->_getSession()->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPost());
            foreach ($errorMessages as $errorMessage) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($errorMessage);
            }
            $this->_redirect('*/*/resetpassword', array(
                'id' => $customerId,
                'token' => $resetPasswordLinkToken
            ));
            return;
        }

        try {
            // Empty current reset password token i.e. invalidate it
            $customer->setRpToken(null);
            $customer->setRpTokenCreatedAt(null);
            $customer->setConfirmation(null);
            $customer->save();
            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(Mage::helper('customer')->__('Your password has been updated.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/login');
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            $this->_getSession()->addException($exception, $this->__('Cannot save a new password.'));
            $this->_redirect('*/*/resetpassword', array(
                'id' => $customerId,
                'token' => $resetPasswordLinkToken
            ));
            return;
        }
    }
```

I above function i have commented the line no 646

```
$errorMessages = array_merge($errorMessages, $validationErrorMessages);
```